Error trying to use ./gradlew clean shadowJar
I'm getting the following error while trying to use Gradle to execute a work project
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.8
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
I don't understand why the location is invalid
